# Android WebView local html cannot get file from a URL

Tags: android, webview

I've a webview that loads a local html file. The problem is simple. It cannot load something from any url, an image, a js file etc.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://website.com/myimage.jpg" />
</body>
```

I added necessary permission tag into my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I'm not using cordova/phonegap. It just a webview that loads a local html file.

```
WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

I've been searching since the morning and nothing works. I promise I'm going to pray until end of my life for the one who solves this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Put your file in assets folder and use

```
webView.loadurl("file:///android_asset/yourfilename.html");
```

Hope it helps thanks.